# difference between Cyclic subspace and f-Invariant subspace

Tags: cyclic-groups, invariant-subspace

I would like to clarify the the difference between an f-Invariant subspace above V and a cyclic subspace Z(v;T).
I understand that all cyclic subspaces are f-Invariant.
But why aren't all f-Invariant subspaces cyclic ?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at a nilpotent $f$ with only a Jordan block of size $3$ and another of size $2$. The image of $f$ is $f$-invariant, and has dimension $3$, but it is not cyclic because for that we would need $x$ such that $fx,f^2x,f^3x$ is a basis of the range, but $f^3=0$.